# Python: How do I use alsa 'devices' like hw:0,0 and hw:1,0 in amixer to set the output volume?

Tags: linux, python, alsa

I'm using subprocess.call commands like:

```
aplay --device=plughw:1,0 test.wav
aplay --device=plughw:0,0 test.wav
```

to play sounds on my headset or speakers, and that works fine.  I'm deriving the above devices from sounddevice.query_devices()

and I'm also using:

```
amixer set Headphone 60%
```

where that name is derived from alsaaudio.mixers()

How do I use the hw:0,0 device to tell amixer which device I want to control the volume of?  Or how do I translate hw:x,y devices to amixer names?  Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Thanks!

Followup:
Hmm, if I just say 'amixer' I get:

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 338
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 169 [50%] [-31.72dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 169 [50%] [-31.72dB] [on]
```

and I can use `amixer set PCM 60%`, but nothing else works, and I can't see the name of the headset.

```
amixer set --device hw:0,0 60%
Specify what you want to set...
```

Comment: `amixer` has the option `-c` for you to select the card to manipulate. Since the device (`y`) does not matter in this context anyway, you only need to specify the card (`x`). (There's actually also an option `-D` which I have no idea under what circumstances one would need that specified.)

Comment: You are not reading. Run `amixer -c 0` and `amixer -c 1` to set what mixer controls they have respectively.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, thank you.  More not comprehending than not reading, but I appreciate your patience.  #OnceYouKnowItsObvious